# Group by array element in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

We have nested document and trying to group by array element. Our document structure looks like

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a690a4287e0e50010af1432"),
    "slug" : [ 
        "true-crime-the-10-most-infamous-american-murder-mysteries", 
        "10-most-infamous-american-murder-mysteries"
    ],
    "tags" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "59244aa6b1be5055278e9b5b",
            "name" : "true crime",
            "_id" : "59244aa6b1be5055278e9b5b"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "5924524db1be5055278ebd6e",
            "name" : "Occult Museum",
            "_id" : "5924524db1be5055278ebd6e"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "5a690f0fc1a72100110c2656",
            "_id" : "5a690f0fc1a72100110c2656",
            "name" : "murder mysteries"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "59244d71b1be5055278ea654",
            "name" : "unsolved murders",
            "_id" : "59244d71b1be5055278ea654"
        }
    ]
}
```

We want to find list of all slugs group by tag name. I am trying with following and it gets result but it isn't accurate. We have hundreds of records with each tag but i only get few with my query. I am not sure what i am doing wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

```js
// Requires official MongoShell 3.6+

db.getCollection("test").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "item_type" : "Post", 
                "site_id" : NumberLong(2), 
                "status" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
  {$unwind: "$tags" },         
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "tags᎐name" : "$tags.name",
                    "slug" : "$slug"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "tags.name" : "$_id.tags᎐name",
                "slug" : "$_id.slug",
                "_id" : NumberInt(0)
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : true
    }
);
```

Expected output is

```
TagName     Slug
----------
true crime "true-crime-the-10-most-infamous-american-murder-mysteries", 
           "10-most-infamous-american-murder-mysteries"
           "All records where tags true crime"
```

Comment: can you update the question with expected output of the query you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `slug` as a part of `_id` you should use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/index.html) or [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/index.html) to accumulate them, try:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$tags"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$slug"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$tags.name",
            slugs: { $addToSet: "$slug" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            slugs: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$slugs",
                    initialValue: "",
                    in: {
                        $concat: [ "$$value", ",", "$$this" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

EDIT: to get comma separated string for slugs you can use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) with [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/#exp._S_concat)

Output:

```
{ "_id" : "murder mysteries", "slugs" : ",10-most-infamous-american-murder-mysteries,true-crime-the-10-most-infamous-american-murder-mysteries" }
{ "_id" : "Occult Museum", "slugs" : ",10-most-infamous-american-murder-mysteries,true-crime-the-10-most-infamous-american-murder-mysteries" }
{ "_id" : "unsolved murders", "slugs" : ",10-most-infamous-american-murder-mysteries,true-crime-the-10-most-infamous-american-murder-mysteries" }
{ "_id" : "true crime", "slugs" : ",10-most-infamous-american-murder- mysteries,true-crime-the-10-most-infamous-american-murder-mysteries" }
```

Comment: This is almost what i need. Is there a way to have slug as comma separated string than Array ? I need to export this data into excel and it creates unnecessary empty columns

Comment: @jvm modified my answer